# unzip -j -o not working through Ansible, but working directly on host

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, unzip, rhel

I am trying to grab one file from app.war called *test.properties*, this command works perfectly on a RHEL host when I run it directly on it:

```sh
unzip -j -o /home/test/app.war "*test.properties*"
```

**But**, when I run the same thing in Ansible, it does not work, it does not extract anything, there is no change:

```yaml
- name: Extract test.properties file
  shell: 'unzip -j -o /home/test/app.war "*test.properties*"'
```

FYI, I CANNOT use Unarchive Module due to Ansible being version 2.9 . Am I doing anything wrong Ansible side? Maybe I am missing something extra like sudo or quotes?

Comment: which shell does ansible run in? could it be it runs in `sh` and you were testing with `bash`? It might affect the way the asterisk is interpreted.

Comment: it runs in sh  i believe, any other suggestions @ChristianFritz ? I cannot use unarchive module because I have ansible 2.9 which does not have the 'include' parameter....

Answer (score 1):

It would actually be a better idea to get what you learned in your previous question and to feed it back in the proper Ansible module: [`unarchive`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html), as it **does** allow you to feed the `-j` option in the [`extra_opts` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html#parameter-extra_opts).

Given the task:

```yaml
- unarchive:
    src: /home/test/app.war 
    dest: /tmp
    include:
      - '*test.properties'
    extra_opts:
      - -j
```

You will get any file ending in *test.properties* only, thanks to the [`include` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html#parameter-include), extracted in the */tmp* folder without any of its original path structure, thanks to the option `-j` given to `extra_opts`.

---

Since you are on a 2.9 version of Ansible — which I really recommend you to upgrade, [due to its end of life being 31 December 2021](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine) — what you can do it to use the trick raised in this comment from Ansible issue tracker:

> The `extra_opt`s are placed before the module arguments, with the .zip file before the filename to extract. The error resulting from the .zip file argument placed by the module may then be ignored by `ignore_errors: yes`

*Source: [@ossm1db comment on Ansible issue tracker](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27081)*

But, we can try to have a better hack, with the usage of `failed_when` in order to have as less false positive as possible, something like:

```yaml
- unarchive:
    src: /home/test/app.war
    dest: /tmp
    extra_opts:
      - -j 
      - /home/test/app.war
      - '*test.properties'
  register: _unarchive
  failed_when:
    - "not _unarchive.extract_results.out is search(
        'extracting: .*/test.properties'
      )"
    - _unarchive.extract_results.rc != 0
```

Two things to note here:

1. Mind that, the path to the WAR file have to be repeated in the `src` parameter and the `extra_opts` one, that is what makes it a ugly solution that called for the addition of `include` in later version.
2. There are false positive that might arise here, with the usage of `failed_when`, namely the command could fail behind the scene, but Ansible will still marks it as `ok`, as long as the regex `extracting: .*/test.properties` is matched in the extraction output. This is actually what *@ossm1db* is raising in their comment in the issue tracker quoted above.

Comment: Hi, I get the following error - it is not finding include: as a parameter : msg": "Unsupported parameters for (unarchive) module: include Supported parameters include: attributes, backup, content, creates, delimiter, dest, directory_mode, exclude, extra_opts, follow, force, group, keep_newer, list_files, mode, owner, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate_certs",

Comment: i also added remote_src: yes because I download the war file already in my local

Comment: [_added in 2.11_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html#parameter-include) what is your version of Ansible?

Comment: hi, Ansible version is 2.9.20, oh it looks like my version of ansible does not have include then... im back to square one :( .

Comment: @testcodezz the obvious answer to this would be: [***upgrade, your version is out of support since last year***](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine).

Comment: @testcodezz answer updated with a possible solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not up to me to upgrade Ansible, i have to work with what I have, I am still very confused why shell: 'unzip -j -o /home/test/app.war "*test.properties*"' did not work .......

Comment: did not work meaning it did not extract anything through ansible... it did extract the file when working directly on the host tho...

Comment: Does anyone have any other recommendations please ? Unarchive module will not work for me unfortunately :(